# Why is my edited answer is marked as edited by another user?

Tags: support, edits

I have made an edit to somebody's answer this morning, but I have not received alert about if it was accepted or not. Curiously, I went to the question page and I realize that my edit was applied but as if it was edited by another user. How is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9767875) is the suggestion you're referring to.

Your suggestion was rejected by three out of four reviewers. Then another person [made almost the same edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16282990/2). I don't know why the new edit was so similar to yours (and unless the editor sees this post there's no real way to be sure), but the edits are small enough that's it's possible for it to be coincidence. It's also possible that they reviewed your suggestion and wanted to approve it, but it was rejected before they could. If that happened, then they could have decided it was worthwhile to simply apply it themselves.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar You can see your own suggestions under your profile in activity->all actions->suggestions, or just go to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1914034/below-the-radar?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Comment: ok thank you! But why the same suggestion from another user was accepted ?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar They have over 2000 reputation, so they don't need to have their edits reviewed before being applied.

Comment: Ok well, thats fine! Thank you all for the info